# Execute a Java program in a PHP-script as CGI-Module

Tags: php, cgi, exec

I'm trying to execute a Java Program in a PHP Script.
Unfortunately this does not work, when I execute PHP as CGI.
For testing I tried to execute the following PHP script:

javaversion.php:

```
<?php
 echo exec("java -version");
?>
```

When I run it using php.exe I got the desired result.
But it failed with php-cgi.exe. Both are in the same directory, have access to the same php.ini file and have the same (correct) environment variables.
I have also reproduced this on a second, clean Windows server.

I also tried the following functions without success: `shell_execute()`, `system()`, `passthru()`

My question is now: Why do php.exe and php-cgi.exe that different and what possibilities do exist to run a Java program with a PHP-CGI-Module, because I'm dependent on PHP as CGI-Module on my target system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When the php-cgi version fails, what is the error message? also, even though env vars are the same you might perhaps try the full path to java?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not get any error message. And the full path to java did not help too.

Comment: Strange... even with all errors enabled there is no messages? 
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
echo exec("java -version");
?>

Comment: Yes, they are enabled.

The problem is that I cannot execute java.exe. Every other cmd-command I tried worked normally. And I checked my path to java.exe several times